# Location of robots.txt file in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, robots.txt

Where can I find the location of `robots.txt` file in the Magento root?

Checked `pub` folder also.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configured a magento for generating robot.txt file.

Please follow this tutorial

https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/create-robots-txt-magento-2/

Comment: thanks for the note, I'm having an idea how to configure it from a backend, but I want the location of the robots.txt file

Answer (score 1):

It must be in root directory.
Check this file here

```
<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Admin/Robots.php
```

First create `robots.txt` in root folder, `give permission 777` and then follow this tutorial

https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/create-robots-txt-magento-2/

Thanks